# Increments Word Problem (Business Calculus)

Tags: calculus

Here is a word problem I found concerning increments.

[image]

Okay so I know the approximation is $P\approx P'(t)\Delta t$ where

$P'(t)=-3t^2+18t+48$ and $\Delta t=\frac{1}{12}$. Since the change corresponds to starting at $t=2$ to $t=2\frac{1}{12}$, we will end up plugging in $2$ in for $t$. Putting everything together we get,

$P \approx (-3(2)^2+18(2)+48)(\frac{1}{12}) \approx 6$

However the percent change is found by doing $\frac{P'(t)}{P(t)}\times 100$.

$P(2)=324$ but then what am I doing for $P'(t)$? I know it seems like you would just plug $2$ in (maybe??), but then what was the point of finding the approximation of $6$ for $P$?

Comment: Approximating change by differentials just gives you a rough idea - the derivative gives an exact number. I'll give a detailed answer later unless someone beats me to it (in about an hour and a half).

Answer (score 0):

you could say $\frac {P(2\frac 1{12}) - P(2)}{P(2)}$

Some books will say: $\frac {P(2\frac 1{12}) - P(2)}{\frac 12 (P(2\frac 1{12})+P(2))}$

But if an approximation will suffice.
Then $(\frac 1{12})(\frac {P'(2)}{P(2)})$ will do.

$\frac {P(2\frac 1{12}) - P(2)}{P(2)} = \frac {330-324}{324}=1.86\%$

$(\frac 1{12})(\frac {P'(2)}{P(2)}) = (\frac 1{12})(\frac {72}{324}) = 1.85\%$

Comment: I am not sure I follow the last line. I thought percent change was just $\frac{P'(2)}{P(2)}\times 100$??

Comment: that would be anualized, though ant the question is asks for monthly.  Hence the $\frac1{12}$ factor.  (Which I see in the OP).